# How do I access Mosaico on CiviCRM Spark instance?

Tags: mosaico, civicrm-spark

My client paid the upgraded fee for CiviCRM Spark Hosting with CiviMail and Mosaico. CiviMail is working, but Mosaico isn't under Mailings as it is in other CiviCRM instances I work with. I also can't find anywhere to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

It is an Extension and you would need to 'install' it via the Extension page. Administer > System Settings > Extension

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears  Spark users can't install additional or upgrade Extensions, yet. However, if the site was upgraded to add Mosaico, that should appear as an Enabled extension at Administer -> System Settings -> Extensions and at Mailings -> Mosaico Templates. If it does not, please contact the Spark folks at chat.civicrm.org in the ~spark channel. You may also want to run Administer -> System Settings -> Cleanup Caches.